# Why is encoding VP8/9 so slow compared to H.264?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding, codec

Recently I wanted to try out the Webm codecs VP8 and VP9 but when I ran `ffmpeg` to encode a H.264 MP4 file into one of the other two codecs, I realized that the encoding is (by almost an order of magnitude) slower.

A 1080p30 video from H.264 to VP9 at 3 MBit/s is being encoded at around 6-7 fps while the same video encodes at around 40 fps to H.264. I used the `libvpx-vp9` codec in `ffmpeg` for the VP9 format. I am getting the same results for VP8 and Theora too.

Can someone explain to me why VP9 is so much slower? I tried a different machine which gave me similar resullts using Handbrake.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270625/how-to-fast-convert-mp4-to-webm-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 15):

`libvpx-vp9` is a much slower encoder than `libx264` but the default settings of threads in ffmpeg (0=auto) is not effective for libvpx. Manually setting it gives a speed bump. e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -threads 4 out.mp4
```

On a 4-core machine, when encoding a 1080-30p H.264 stream, I get a bump from `3.8 fps` to `10 fps`.

Comment: One should also mention that there are different speed presets, i.e., `-preset` for `libx264` and `-speed` for `libvpx-vp9`. See `ffmpeg -h full`. These can make quite a difference, but they also affect quality or compression efficiency.

Comment: I tried it on rather old machines but I did use 4 threads since both machines are quad-core. The `-speed` option didn't make a huge difference for me

Comment: @comfreak See also: https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/the-basics/

Answer (score 4):

VP9 is a more more complex codec providing better compression. Video compression/performance ratio tends to be exponentially. You should expect the VP9 replacement (AV1) to be even slower.

Comment: So in other words, even though the codec "only" produces a relatively small size improvement, it may be much slower? Are the results I got representative?

Comment: VP9 can be up to 50% more efficient in terms of quality, @comfreak. I wouldn't call that small. You can't just compare the resulting file size.

Comment: @slhck: So you are saying that 3MBit/s can encode more original information than H.264 and therefore a lower bit rate than the source material in H.264 might be an option to speed things up?

Comment: @comfreak Using a lower bitrate will not automatically increase the speed of the encoding process. I'm just saying that there is a tradeoff between compression efficiency and speed, and many streaming providers for example would rather invest the CPU time to create higher quality streams at lower overall bitrate, to conserve space and bandwidth. Using more efficient codecs (like VP9 or HEVC over H.264) also helps in that regard.

Comment: But essentially, if speed is the most important factor for you, you should stick with older codecs (e.g., H.264), less compression-efficient presets, and perhaps also look into GPU-assisted encoding, e.g. with NVENC.